# How to trigger jenkins multi-branch pipeline build from a gitlab merge request from a fork?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

Folks,

I'm actually having loads of fun since switching to multibranch pipelines in Jenkins which i use in combination with GitLab. 
But something i still do not wrap my head around is how to build merge request that originates from a fork - the ones coming from the same remote triggers a build but not the ones from my fork !

I'd be really happy to hear any idea about this.

Thanks a lot community !

Comment: Have you tried to create another job to build you MR from your fork? With a webhook that triggers it on MR event?

Comment: do you suggest i should make a job per fork ? :(

Comment: Just one job to see if it works. I'm just saying that doing things unitarily may help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try a different approach:

A multibranch pipeline is for continuous build (with only compilation and testing). This is basically a quick feedback on our current work.

Building a MR is altogether another business. It is supposed to provide all necessary elements to the reviewer to determine wether a MR can be merged on the master branch or not. Therefore, it could imply code quality analysis, security analysis, gating, dashboards...

With this respect, it should be separated in different jobs.

Having two seperate jobs for the two functionalities is not only cleaner, but I believe, it would solve your trigger from fork problem.

Comment: I'm re-reading your question, and i am wondering: is there any link between the multibranch and the MR from forks issue? (appart from the fact that you are having fun, and which is great!!)